# "vagrant up" fails while building devenv for Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: vagrant, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I cloned the repo and run `vagrant up`as instructed [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/devenv/). Then it fails:

```
==> default: Step 11 : RUN /hyperledger/scripts/provision/common.sh
==> default:  ---> Running in b8ef04b89dee
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: E
==> default: : 
==> default: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: W
==> default: : 
==> default: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: W
==> default: : Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
==> default: E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
==> default: E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
==> default: 
==> default: The command '/bin/sh -c /hyperledger/scripts/provision/common.sh' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295
==> default: make: *** [build/image/base/.dummy] Error 255
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

And I have no clue on how to fix this. I guess my connection might have failed while it was building? Not sure on how to restart the process since running `vagrant up` again just says the VM is already running. `vagrant ssh` fails, `echo $?` says 255.

Comment: could you please follow the instructions posted here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505775/debian-apt-packages-hash-sum-mismatch

Comment: besides, could you try running `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` before executing `sudo vagrant up` ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to restart the process (rebuild and restart your environment) you can halt your VM, and destroy it.

To do so you can check your machine status, name and id using 
`vagrant gloabl-status`

Then from your `/devenv` folder execute:

- `vagrant halt` specifying either name or id - to power-off your
  machine
- `vagrant destroy` - to destroy your VM

Then you start from beginning with `vagrant up`