# ERROR in Docker Installation on Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphql, prisma-graphql

I'm really new to docker and having problem in installation. I have used all the things available on internet, also installed it twice to check and also used the `--fix-missing` flag. The main problem is this, After this installation if I'm running `docker --version`, its printing its version perfectly, but the deamon is not running in the background and I have done a lot of effort to start the deamon but I'm failed. The main picture of my goal is install docker successfully & run the deamon.

[image: Error picture 01]

[image: Error picture 02]

Comment: Please paste errors and code into your question directly, using the quote or code block formatting. Don't provide errors or code as images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debian apt packages hash sum mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505775/debian-apt-packages-hash-sum-mismatch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

if this doesn't work, try `sudo apt update` with a different internet connection 
and then install docker-ce. This is not your computer's problem. It is a problem from your ISP. I often face it with my ISP then I use different connection and it works. I am sorry I can't explain why it happens. I don't know the cause.

Comment: It worked without giving me the error but the deamon is not starting. Its giving me error:


ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

Comment: `sudo systemctl status docker` <- for checking status,
`sudo systemctl start docker` <- for running the service,
`sudo systemctl enable docker` <- for starting docker at startup

Comment: Yup done that before. The Active status is dead in output. Can you please tell me how to start the docker deamon. Thanks a lot!!